# Adding index exemption has no effect on document updates

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

TLDR: Adding an index exemption seemingly doesn't work for updates? What am I doing wrong?

In Firestore we have a collection `accessGroups` with large documents that contain the embedded maps of `locks` and `users`. We started hitting the *"too many index entries for entity"* error when adding new large documents. There is no need to query on `users` or `locks`, so I tried adding single index exemptions:

```yaml
fieldOverrides: [
  {
    "collectionGroup": "accessGroups",
    "fieldPath": "users",
    "indexes": []
  },
  {
    "collectionGroup": "accessGroups",
    "fieldPath": "locks",
    "indexes": []
  }]
```

After adding the exemption I use the Firebase CLI to verify that the indices has been removed:

```yaml
metadata:
  '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.firestore.admin.v1.FieldOperationMetadata
  endTime: '2023-09-12T12:02:18.923772Z'
  field: projects/my-project/databases/(default)/collectionGroups/accessGroups/fields/users
  indexConfigDeltas:
  - changeType: REMOVE
    index:
      fields:
      - fieldPath: users
        order: ASCENDING
      queryScope: COLLECTION
  - changeType: REMOVE
    index:
      fields:
      - fieldPath: users
        order: DESCENDING
      queryScope: COLLECTION
  - changeType: REMOVE
    index:
      fields:
      - arrayConfig: CONTAINS
        fieldPath: users
      queryScope: COLLECTION
  progressDocuments:
    completedWork: '222'
    estimatedWork: '222'
  startTime: '2023-09-12T11:58:17.756350Z'
  state: SUCCESSFUL
```

After this I was able to add new large documents to the collection. However, updating the large documents still doesn't work. I still get the *"too many index entries for entity"*.

What could be the cause of this?